# Restricting selection of items on selection of specific item in Multiselect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, multi-select, flutter-plugin

I am using multiselect pugin to implement multiselect list in my flutter project. In the project I want to add the functionality like,
the option in list are all, first, second, third
Now when I select the all option then the multiselect should restrict the user from selecting other options as he has already selected all option. and when user selects the remaining options from the list except all then he should be restricted from selecting all.
Is it possible to achieve in flutter? I've tried few options like restricting the list showing values or adding vlidation but not getting expected result.
The plugin I am using is: https://pub.dev/packages/multiselect
Please help me with the slution...
I wouldn't mind using custom build multilist with expected properties.

[image: There should be restriction when user selects all]

Comment: Please be more clear with your question. But looking at it seems like you can easily do that with conditional statements on the callback of those items.

Comment: Keep track of all the selected answers and then add checks to restrict user.

Comment: I am handling the data selected by the user with conditionals but I want to do the same in the UI, Like if the user selects the (ALL tab) of multi-select then he should not be able to select other items from the multi-select.

Comment: You can add a check, that if the selected items include "All" then do not add the new clicked option in the selected items (you can show a snack bar or something for the user to know)